# mongodump.exe and mongorestore.exe files are missing

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

Yesterday I reinstalled Windows 10 on my PC and downloaded and installed the current version of MongoDB Enterprise from the MongoDB website. After installing MongoDB, it works fine. But the mongodump.exe and mongorestore.exe files are missing in the C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin directory. So, I cannot restore my previous database and continue my work. Am I doing anything wrong? How can I get those files back so that I can restore my previous database?

Comment: Which version have you installed? quick will be get https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass and follow  https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/import-export/

Comment: Can you check which folder has mongo.exe  ?

Comment: I installed enterprise-4.4.4
The folder C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin has the mongo.exe file

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting with Mongo 4.4 the database tools are not part of the MongoDB Server package anymore.

You have to download **MongoDB Database Tools** separately from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was doing something wrong. Didn't know that the Database Tools were separated.

Comment: these tools don't contain mongorestore. How to use them?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko They do, have a careful look.